uniswap v3_QUOTER2 strange units of function quoteExactInput
Hi i try to find price for matic in usdc with uniswap api and python web3.
This is code fragment:
matic_address = "0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270"
usdc_address = "0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174" # usdc
UNISWAP_v3_QUOTER2_ADDRESS = "0x61fFE014bA17989E743c5F6cB21bF9697530B21e"


# load the contracts
quoter2_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=UNISWAP_v3_QUOTER2_ADDRESS, abi=UNISWAP_V3_QUOTER2_ABI)


path = eth_abi.packed.encode_packed(['address','uint24','address'], [matic_address, 3000, usdc_address])
amount_to_buy_for = int(1 * 10**18)

amount_out, sqrtPriceX96After, initializedTicksCrossed, gasEstimate = quoter2_contract.functions.quoteExactInput(path, amount_to_buy_for).call()
print(amount_out)

737110

I try to find here the price of 1 matic in usdc ... and I get us result integer 737110
and it looks like real price 0.73$ at a monent.. but I expect something as real price but not this big int 737110 ... can somebody explain what happens here ? and how i get real price in a common case? and why in this case i must divide it to 1M to get real price of 1 matic in usdc.e?
